# MVC checkbox needs to be unchecked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox

I have a few checkboxes values of which are posted to action, and when action calls the view again the checkboxes are checked according to their previous state:

```
<div class="D2">@Html.CheckBox("int", false, new { id = "int" })</div>
<div class="D2">@Html.CheckBox("ext", false, new { id = "ext" })</div>
<div class="D2">@Html.CheckBox("none", false, new { style = "visibility:hidden", id = "none" }
</div>
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Images(bool? int, bool? ext, bool? none)
return View();
```

But I want the third theckbox ALWAYS to be unchecked, while the other ones should keep the settings. How can I achieve that please?

Comment: So you are setting the checked state explicitly to `false` and it still appears checked!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Html` helper methods ALWAYS get the value from `ModelState` if they can.
To ensure the third checkbox will be unchecked, you should clear the `ModelState` value in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Images(bool? int, bool? ext, bool? none) {
    ModelState.Remove("none");
    return View();
}
```

For more info, see [`ModelState.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470162.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to always be unchecked, why even send it into the method, simply use a value of false in your ActionResult. It doesn't have to be present in the parameter list.
Am I not following something here?